# Conditional Data Extraction using dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I have to copy range of data from multiple columns based on cell name match with sheet name. However, the range of data against each ID in column "A" is not the same in case of some matched sheet name we have 30 data and in some cases we may have 20 data or any other value. My current code enables me to extract data from "combine" sheet to template sheets having matched sheet name. Instead of extracting 30 datas using offset from match range how can I make the code dynamic and extract data based on changed sheetname in column A (there are some blank cells after each borehole name upto next name in column "A" which needs to be considered for development of the VBA code) and copy the data corresponding to that name  from column M and S and paste in template sheets in columns E and G based on matched sheet name. Currently I am able to extract data from one column only, the code needs to be updated dynamicallY:

```
Sub SPT()
Dim wkSht As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Sheets("Combine").Range("A5:A116").Cells

    For Each wkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        If cell.Value = wkSht.Name Then
       
            Sheets("Combine").Range(cell.Offset(0, 12), cell.Offset(29, 12)).Copy wkSht.Range("G22")
        End If
    
    Next wkSht

Next cell
End Sub
```

[image: Data Extraction]

Comment: So if always copy 12 row from `main sheet`, what is the issue for the `copy paste`? Because it won't be any problem to copy same row even contain blank value.

Comment: the row copy option has to be dynamic with respect to  cell A value with sheetnames. corresponding columns at a specific offset will have to be copied in different sheets based on sheet name match within the range also, now I would like to copy data from multiple columns instead of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The copy paste process will be offset depend on the cell value in `Col H`, please test and run it, thanks:

```
Sub SPT()
Dim wkSht As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim lastrow As Long, blankRow As Long, offsetRow As Long

lastrow = Sheets("Combine").UsedRange.Rows.Count

For Each cell In Sheets("Combine").Range("A2", "A" & lastrow).Cells

    For Each wkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        If cell.Value = wkSht.Name Then
        
            If cell.End(xlDown).Row > lastrow Then
                blankRow = lastrow
            Else
                blankRow = cell.End(xlDown).Row - 1
            End If
            
            offsetRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Sheet1.Cells(blankRow, 8).Value, 0)
            Sheets("Combine").Range(cell.Offset(0, 12), cell.Offset(offsetRow, 12)).Copy wkSht.Range("G22")
            Sheets("Combine").Range(cell.Offset(0, 18), cell.Offset(offsetRow, 18)).Copy wkSht.Range("E22")
        End If
    
    Next wkSht

Next cell
End Sub
```

Assume you last sheet name in `Col A` is row 14, and below is blank data

[image]

When you use keyboard shortcut `ctrl + down arrow key`, it will jump to row 1mil, since I know such situation will happen but I don't want to obtain `row 1mil`, therefore I will set `blankRow = lastrow(i.e. 20)`

[image]

Comment: Instead off fixing the offset rows from 0 to 29 we have to make it dynamic and dependent of cell value of "A". for example the 1st match name starts at A2, second one at A15 and third one at A26. in that case the offset rows corresponding to BH1, BH2 and BH3 sheet name will be from 0 to 14, 0 to 11 and 0 to 10 (last range value). How can this be materialized: [link](https://ibb.co/FVT0bWb)

Comment: ok, i get your point, let me try work it out, not much issue.

Comment: You may check my edited answer, should work properly as per your expectation

Comment: It does not work for the last match as it has empty cells below it after the data entry. However, what does used range refer to? Also I don't understand the following portion of the code: If cell.End(xlDown).Row > lastrow Then
                blankRow = lastrow
            Else
                blankRow = cell.End(xlDown).Row - 1
            End If
            
            offsetRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Sheet1.Cells(blankRow, 8).Value, 0)

Comment: Please spend time to do research, as all the explanation for the code can be found online...Regarding your last match, I have no idea about, you may manually change it or figure out adjustment and I think I will close case now, thank you.

Comment: Try debug step by step to understand what is the function doing, you will only learn by test it yourself...

Comment: I will explain this part as this is hard to understand ` If cell.End(xlDown).Row > lastrow Then blankRow = lastrow `. The reason is that, when you are only the `last sheet name in Col A`, when you press `ctrl + down arrow` it will jump to beyond your actual `last row (i.e 116)` in your data (like 100k row), to prevent obtain more than actual last row, I set the condition for it. See the explanation above and hope you enjoy learn VBA :)

Comment: In addition to this can we add 30 row data for the last sheet instead of nothing entered in the sheet

Comment: You can try if sheetname is equal to your last sheet name, then assign row 30. I think the main problem is the `structure` of your sheet data, instead of the `VBA code`....